# Add 'dots' to UIDatePicker calendar to signify event on date?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I'm using the UIDatePicker calendar in my iOS app. When a user taps on a date (ie. Nov 21), it shows a list of all events happening on that date for the user inside a tableview. Having said that, there doesn't seem to be any way to add a "dot" on the actual UIDatePicker calendar date to signify that an event exists on it. **For example**, if I have an array containing a list of dates:

```objc
self.eventDates = @[
    [self dateFromString:@"2023-11-20"],
    [self dateFromString:@"2023-11-25"],
];
```

I'd like a dot to be drawn on the listed UIDatePicker dates.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this? I can't seem to find examples anywhere.

Comment: You can't customise the calendar display of `UIDatePicker`. You would need to create your own view of find an open source component

Comment: You are looking for `UICalendarView`.